# Plotting x-axis in log scale spacing but not labeling it in exponential form

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot say two values `x = [0, 10,20,50,100]` and  `y=[1,2,3,10,100]`  using pylab. I want to keep the spacing of  x-axis in log form. But I want to tick at the values of x i'e at 10, 20, 50, 100 and print them as it not in the form of 10e1 or 10e2.  I am doing it as follows:

```
 import matplotlib.pylab as plt
 plt.xscale('log')
 plt.plot(x, y)
 plt.xticks(x)
 plt.grid()
```

But it keeps the values in the form of 10e1, 10e2.

Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is to change the `major_formatter` of the x axis?

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

x = [0, 10,20,50,100]
y=[1,2,3,10,100]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.grid()

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(x[1:]) # note that with a log axis, you can't have x = 0 so that value isn't plotted.
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image: scalar_formatter]

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,10,20,50,100]
y = [1,2,3,10,100]

f,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
ax.set_xlim([0,100])
```

will produce

[image]